# SharePoint export into Excel with Multiple-Choice column

Tags: sharepoint-online, excel

We're using SharePoint Online (Office 365) and Excel 2013.  Can you configure a multiple-choice column in a SharePoint list to have the answers be exported into 
**individual cells** in Excel 2013?  We're allowing more than one answer in the multiple-choice column, but when it exports into Excel all of the answers get combined into one cell with a hash tag in-between them, which makes reporting a hassle.

Answer (score 2):

I guess first you should export to excel format and Merge what ever you want to the cell.

https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2013/10/13/merge-columns-excel-without-losing-data/

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do this that I've found. You can filter the column in SharePoint that has the multiple choice, I would suggest the easiest way is to create a new view and filter data if appropriate within SharePoint.

You could also group items in the view options, see if that makes it easier

Otherwise you're stuck trying to split the data apart in Excel

Answer (score 0):

Considering that multiple choice columns basically create one-to-many relations with another entity, you would really want to expert the list item as many times as you have selected choices and have each exported line have one unique selected value. I have not yet found a way to make SharePoint do this. It involves either manual post-processing in Excel or setting up your SharePoint list differently and not allowing multiple choice fields.